# Jenkins Batch Commands Inconsistent

Tags: windows, batch-file, jenkins, psexec

I am experiencing some inconsistent behaviour with Jenkins when running batch commands. They either work or they don't at random, I am struggling to find the cause of this.

Jenkins 2.62 is being used and the batch command takes place using a standard "Execute Windows batch command" build step. The command pretty much just launches a Remote Desktop session: psexec -i -d mstsc "C:\VM.RDP"

I have tried all kinds of different approaches to launching the RDP file and this is the only one that seems to keep the remote session active without closing it when the job completes. I have also had the highest success rate with this command.

I have similar setup on another Jenkins server on another network with zero issues. The job on the other server also just uses the mstsc command without psexec and does not close the remote session when the job finishes.

Comment: where is the code you have tried?

Comment: it is mentioned above, psexec -i -d mstsc "C:\VM.RDP"

Comment: @GerhardBarnard do you have any advice or idea as to what might be happening?